# How to identify OS interrupts in java code and perform some action?

Tags: java, operating-system

Lets assume that there is a vm running on any machine (Linux/windows etc ). Now assuming its on linux machine ,I execute pkill -9 {processId} for the particular vm . I want to know if there is any way in java code to know if the process was interrupted and post interruption I want to execute some backup code or some action  before the process gets killed .

Is it possible ? I just want to get to the basics of this and any clue or suggestion would be highly helpful.

Thanks

Comment: Thanks ! I got the hint I needed .Its precisely what I wanted to know

Comment: Before exiting from java code your shutdown hook is get called if you register any shutdown hook . For more info u can follow this link https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/jvm-shutdown-hook-java/

Comment: thanks ! the link was a great help